# Why doesn't my SkyTexture show up in the preview tab?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, image

I have a problem with an image not showing up in the preview tab for the SkyTexture. In the screenshot below you can see the image is displayed correctly when used as a Background image in the 3d-view. I'm using the image as an environment texture. Any help welcome! (I'm using blender internal).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your world settings, do you have real sky, and environment lighting enabled? Here are the steps to get your desired results. 
Go to the world tab and click real sky, then environment lighting. Then, make sure that you have sky texture selected in the drop down menu off to the right.
Next, go to the textures tab and choose your image. Set the mapping as you already have, and click horizon, and that should do it. The world settings I use are as in the attached screenshot.[image: World settings]
Hope that helps.

Comment: thanx for the reply. I can get it to work using texture type "image or movie" but not as "environment map". Seams odd to me, but maybe it  just doesn't work that way?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't believe that it can be done as an environment map. The only way I've ever known of is as "image or movie".

Comment: Hmm, so what is the texture type "environment map" used for?

Comment: It basically takes a render of the scene and uses it as a texture to create reflections from my understanding. Here's a link to the current Blender documentation, it might help explain a little better as I don't use environment maps myself.  https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/mapping/environment.html